# WPF Listbox SelectedItems

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

how can I get the selected item's value of a list box?

I tried something like this:

```
            foreach (var item in combo_course_op.SelectedItems)
            {
                string s = "select cid from tms_course where course_title = '" + item.ToString() + "'";
            }
```

but it doesnt works..it shows string s as **"select cid from tms_course where course_title ='System.Data.DataRowView'"**

where am I doing wrong?

This is how I data binded:

```
MyCommand = new OdbcCommand("select distinct module_name from tms_class_schedule where class_date ='"+selectedDate+"'", DBConnect.MyConnection);
            dap = new OdbcDataAdapter(MyCommand);
            DS = new DataSet();
            dap.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
            dap.Fill(DS);
            combo_course_op.DataContext = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            combo_course_op.DisplayMemberPath = DS.Tables[0].Columns["module_name"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in combo_course_op.SelectedItems)
{
    string s = "select cid from tms_course where course_title = '" 
             + (item["Title"] as string) + "'"; // if Title is column name. Otherwise replace "Title" with actual column header name
}
```

Comment: I tried but not luck yet; I edited the question pls check out

Comment: How are you receiving item. (ie combo_course_op.SelectedItems type)

Comment: Hi tilak,
I changed  listbox to a listview. I think my data binding method have some error.

List<string> moduleNames = new List<string>();

                while (MyReader.Read())
                {
                    moduleNames.Add(MyReader.GetString(0));
                }

combo_course_op.ItemsSource = moduleNames;


NOW YOUR METHOD WORKS FINE...:)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously your list box is bound to some data source. That means that the items in the list box are not strings, but instances of `DataRowView`. You can cast and get the underlying data object like that:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)item;
<TheRealType> itemOfMyType = (<TheRealType>)drv.Row;
```

where `<TheRealType>` is the actual data type of the item being bound to the list box.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the DisplayMemberPath is set to Columns["module_name"]

Inferring from this, following should work:

```
foreach (var item in combo_course_op.SelectedItems)
{
   string s = "select cid from tms_course where course_title = '" + item["module_name"].ToString() + "'";
}
```

Selected items are DataRow, therefore you have to get the right column for the value to be returned.

Comment: Had no choice, could not make comments yet. You had module_name as column, he used Title...was not sure if that was causing you problems. Only had 49 points so could not comment back and ask..

Comment: Y? dont be..the thing is in his post he mentioned the what is Title is.
thanks anyway :D good luck

Answer (score -1):

You can cast `Item` in its real type :

```
        foreach (var item in combo_course_op.SelectedItems)
        {
            string s = "select cid from tms_course where course_title = '" +
               ((Course)item).Title + "'";
        }
```

Or override `Course.ToString` so it return its title.

**EDIT** (after noticed about `DataRowView`)

Putting DataRowViews in a WPF ComboBox looks like a really bad id. Maybe you should read a tutorial or two about WPF and MVVM.

Comment: Actually, putting `DataRowView` into the WPF list box is the default behavior of the .NET framework when the list box is data-bound.